# AVD manager throws 'the last location provider was disabled' error

Tags: android, mobile, cordova, geolocation

I am trying to create a HTML5 page that will catch the geolocation, but I'm getting an error on AVD manager. It throws 'the last location provider was disabled' error.
i've heard that could go into the setting of the mobile browser and check 'Enable Location' to solve this problem for a real device. 
well i do not know how to config the settings for a avd job. could anyone give me some guide please?

Here's my source code:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
  alert('xxx');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

// onSuccess Geolocation
//
function onSuccess(position) {
  alert('xieiei');
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '  + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />';
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
  alert('ddd');
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to

> Menu--->Settings---->Location & Security

And then **check**

> Use Wireless Network.

Comment: I'm curious. If this doesn't work without "wireless network" location turned on, does that mean that Phonegap is using the phone network rather than GPS?

Answer (score 2):

> "I'm curious. If this doesn't work without "wireless network" location
>   turned on, does that mean that Phonegap is using the phone network
>   rather than GPS? – Mark Jun 3 '12 at 3:20"

To Mark (and user1228021) :

Because different platforms/browsers mix (Android, iOS, Windows / WebKit, Firefox, IE, etc.) do not react the same internally to the W3C Geolocation API spec, you may have to specify options in order to tweak the response (in your case the "true" value):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, {maximumAge:3000,timeout:5000,enableHighAccuracy:true});
```

After having done that programmatically, there is still the phone settings to consider; on Android for instance you MUST turn OFF Wireless and ON GPS in the Location to get GPS accuracy regardless of any programming; I learned all of that the hard way... A.R.